# Using the extension CiviVolunteer, assigning a volunteer to a company, not an event

Tags: civivolunteer

The latest stable version of CiviVolunteer creates a volunteer allows to assign volunteers to events. The documentation says "The features for this release focus on volunteering at events, but the design creates a foundation for adding support for volunteering in a wide variety of situations"

Not being a programmer, I am wondering if it is possible through a workaround to assign volunteers to organisations instead of having to assign them to an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier this year, the CiviCRM community crowdfunded $30,000 to build CiviVolunteer 2.0, which includes the functionality you're describing.  See here: https://civicrm.org/blogs/ginkgofjg/civivolunteer-20-whats-in-the-works.  The beta version should be out in 4-5 weeks.

For now, the workaround is to create a bogus event to attach volunteers to.